# Simple Model for AC Relay

Tags: relay, ltspice

Though for DC Relay this is almost immediately done with a Current Voltage Source, I've been having good trouble by modelling an AC Relay. Since the reactance part of the relay is an inductor, I am using an RL circuit with a Diode as rectifier for the AC Coil.

I have tested several setups, but I cannot make it work. I cannot made the RL Diode circuit to rectify the inductor current so the Relay triggers whenever a 300VAC Sine Source is plugged in. I only get a sinusoidal wave.

With a Capacitor it is almost straightforward, but with an inductor it has been not no intuitive.

Also, I am having problems by stacking two or more relay, that is, passing the same current through several coils. With an enough small trigger current like 0.1A with 100 Ohms at coil resistance, I should have a total current of 3A (one), 1.5A (two), 0.75A (three Relays..). But for some reason, the Diode is unable to handle 300VAC. That's why I am using the VS-E5... Diode Model, the only one I found instead of the 1N4007 (1000V 1A).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Desired Current through Coil
[image]

Comment: Can you trigger the switch W1 based on power?  If so, you could model the coil as an RL series circuit, and close the switch once power reaches some fraction of the power dissipated by the resistor with its nominal voltage applied.

Comment: That should be equal to trigger based on current, since P(t)=I(t)^2R

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to do. I thought at first I understood then, reading further it confused me. The equivalent of an AC relay coil is a bridge rectifier. capacitor and resistor all in parallel with the impedance of the coil. Use the rectified and smoothed DC output to drive a comparator that switches a contact or.... maybe I'm still confused?

Comment: I think R2 is normally a much larger value, unless talking about a very big relay.  Regardless, try removing VS001 and using V{V{R1}/R1} as the source into W1, since what we're concerned with is the current through it.

Comment: @Andyaka Do you have any reference schematic?

Comment: @Brethlosze I was just thinking about how I would implement it so it's in my head.